# Excel averageif with specific cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

basically what i would like to do is find the average of these 3 cells if the number is bigger than 5.  So i tried averageif(c2,e2,h2,”>5”). But because these cells are not range the formula doesn’t work. Is there any advice for me to use different formula

Answer (score 0):

Any of the `*IF(S)` type formula do not like broken ranges.  You will need to use a different formula that accepts arrays:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(CHOOSE({1,2,3},C2,E2,H2)>5,CHOOSE({1,2,3},C2,E2,H2)))
```

Depending on one's version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**AVERAGEIF** doesn’t work on a **non-contiguous range**. You may try as shown below as well. This doesn't need confirmed **CTRL SHIFT ENTER** to press after entering the formula.

Formula used in cell **I2**

```
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(--(CHOOSE({1,2,3},C2,E2,H2))*--(CHOOSE({1,2,3},C2,E2,H2)>5))/INDEX(FREQUENCY((C2,E2,H2),5),2),"")
```

One More Alternative:

```
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(--(CHOOSE({1,2,3},C3,E3,H3))*--(CHOOSE({1,2,3},C3,E3,H3)>5))/SUMPRODUCT(--(CHOOSE({1,2,3},C3,E3,H3)>5)),"")
```

[image: AverageIf for Non-Contiguous Ranges in Excel]

Answer (score 0):

Another option to consider

```
=AVERAGE(IF(INDEX(C2:H2,,{1,3,6})>5,INDEX(C2:H2,,{1,3,6})))
```

Note ^^ this is an array function and (depending on your version) will need confirmed with ctrl+shift+enter not just enter.

If you have Microsoft 365 (Possibly also Excel 2021 though I can't test).

```
=LET(f,INDEX(C2:H2,,{1,3,6}),AVERAGE(IF(f>5,f)))
```

The dynamic calculation of M365 means you can just enter this in.

Answer (score 0):

**Side Note:**

**AVERAGEIF** Function doesn't work on a **non-contiguous ranges** therefore we need to use a separate formula, also if there is a `TEXT` in any one of the cells it needs to bypass the `#DIV/0` error as well and gives us the required output.

So please refer below for the following two alternative formulas,

```
=AVERAGE(IFERROR(--CHOOSE({1,2,3},C2,E2,H2),""))
```

This second formula, has another advantage which the above formula doesn't, works when we need **AVERAGE** from **Multiple sheet cells**

```
=SUM(IFERROR(--CHOOSE({1,2,3},C2,E2,H2),0))/INDEX(FREQUENCY(IFERROR(--CHOOSE({1,2,3},C2,E2,H2),0),0),2)
```

The above formula is an array formula, so if you are not using **Excel 2021** or **O365** then you need to confirm press **CTRL SHIFT ENTER**.

[image: AVERAGE NON-CONTIGUOUS RANGES]